# Make a developer deploy an application under my account to AppStore without giving him my username and password

Tags: ios, app-store

I have a developer how created an app for me to be deployed in AppStore. He said that he needs my user id and password to complete the deployment and I don't want to give that.

I created an email and created an apple ID for him . I login to https://itunesconnect.apple.com using my existing account and added this new apple id under Users and Roles and gave him **Technical role**.

Is this enough for him to deploy applications to AppStore under my account or is there any extra configuration?

**Note:**

- My existing account joined the apple developer program
- The new apple id didn't join the apple developer program
- I am not a technical guy but I want the developer to deploy the app under my account without giving him the ID and password

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Technical role is enough to deploy.

Source from apple docs:

[**Managing Your App in iTunes Connect - Developer - Apple**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/UsingiTunesConnect/UsingiTunesConnect.html)

> The technical role grants the ability to edit the app information
>   stored in iTunes Connect and to view test accounts for certain app
>   services. **The technical role also grants permission to upload a binary
>   to iTunes Connect and submit an app to App Review**.